# how to add a new column (with a header name) at the 2nd column of the existing csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to add a new column and its corresponding values at the 2nd column(right after the 1st column (ID)) of an existing csv file.
I want the name of the new column be 'date' and the values be the actual date. For example, right now I have a data set looks like below:

```
ID age gender income
A  20  male   20000
B  43  female 60000
C  35  female 50000
D  51  male   90000
```

The desired output looks like:

```
ID date     age gender income
A  20181210 20  male   20000
B  20181210 43  female 60000
C  20181210 35  female 50000
D  20181210 51  male   90000
```

Since I'm not an expert at python (a beginner), I searched many posts and collected all the necessary information which applied to my situation and had a code below. But this code gives an output like below:

```
ID  age gender income 20181210
A   20  male   20000  20181210
B   43  female 60000  20181210
C   35  female 50000  20181210
D   51  male   90000  20181210
```

My questions are:
1. how do I add a column name 'date'?
2. how do I put a new column at the 2nd column? (Especially this one, it was difficult for me to find any relevant answer.)

Here's my code:

```
file_r = open("read.csv", "r")
file_w = open("write.csv", "w")

date = "20181210"

for line in file_r:
    li = line.rstrip().split(",")
    li.append(date)

    out_str = ""
    for j in li:
        out_str += j + ","

    out_str =  out_str[0:-1] + "\n"
    file_w.write(out_str)

file_r.close()
file_w.close()
```

I've been searching for many hours and now I'm so frustrated..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ever gave thought about third party library `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pandas. Might not be super performant with a large file...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("read.csv")
df['date'] = "20181210"
df = df[['ID', 'date', 'age', 'gender', 'income']]
df.to_csv("write.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: hey Noah. Thanks. I tried pandas but it gives a warning from warning module saying that columns are mixed. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Comment: The reason why this happens seems that the file is too big and some rows are pushed aside so column and value pairs are not matched.